# bash script, modifying a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-io, scripting

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash


for i in *.csv
do
        echo "i: $i"
        THE_FILE2="$i-2.csv"

        file_read()
        {
                lineno=0
                while read line
                do
                        echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1","$2",,,"$3","$4}'
                        ((lineno++))
                done
        } < $i > $THE_FILE2
        echo "the_file2: $THE_FILE2"
        echo "end"
done

file_read
```

Output:

```
i: 2992.csv
the_file2: 2992.csv-2.csv
end
i: 5415.csv
the_file2: 5415.csv-2.csv
end
i: csa.csv
the_file2: csa.csv-2.csv
end
i: loc.csv
the_file2: loc.csv-2.csv
end
i: visa.csv
the_file2: visa.csv-2.csv
end

$ ls
2992.csv       csa.csv        transform.sh   visa.csv-2.csv
5415.csv       loc.csv        visa.csv
```

Unfortunately, it only does it for the last file in the list.  It's skipping over all the others.  I have a feeling this has something to do with buffering or globbing or something.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you reading the file line by line in your script? Awk does it by default for you. `awk -F, '{print $1","$2",,,"$3","$4}' $i > $THE_FILE2` does what you want probably (untested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `file_read` inside the loop then called it from outside.

It should be the other way around!

You'll may want to pass some of the values through to `file_read` as parameters.

Comment: I would get rid of the function altogether in this case.

Comment: In the example given above, that is probably a good solution - it's small enough that it can remain inline without confusing the code too much.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `file_read` function. Just put that code directly in the for-loop.

Also, why do you use the shell's `read` command and then echo that to a new `awk` command for each line? You can just redirect the entire file to awk, it reads each line automatically.

And you're incrementing `lineno`, but not using it for anything. If you need the line number for something you haven't shown, you can use awk's `NR` variable.

```
for i in *.csv
do
        echo "i: $i"
        THE_FILE2="$i-2.csv"
        awk -F, '{print $1","$2",,,"$3","$4}' < $i > $THE_FILE2
        echo "the_file2: $THE_FILE2"
        echo "end"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

*Unfortunately, it only does it for the last file in the list.*

That's because you are only calling `file_read` once, after the loop.  It only executes it for the last file because the variables `i` and `THE_FILE2` remain from the last iteration of the loop.

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk -f - *.csv << 'EOD'
BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }
{
    out = FILENAME "-2.csv"
    print $1,$2,",",$3,$4 >> out
}
EOD
```